# Size of relative positioned parent of absolute children

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

If an element which is relative positioned has all children absolute positioned. How to make the parent take actual size using CSS.

Comment: Once you apply `position: absolute` to an element it is taken out of flow, what is the layout you're trying to achieve?

Comment: It's possibly worth saying that absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Try [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)